# Angular Upgrade correct process

Tags: angular, npm, upgrade, angular-upgrade

We are upgrading angular from 4 to 5 and we have followed all of the instructions which are provided by the angular update tool

https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=4.0-5.0

But we are getting many third-party packages(like lodash, datatable, jquery, etc) with strange errors, for each package we need to find some solutions either through google search or library GitHub issues also ask for some solutions on StackOverflow and out of all these platforms we are implementing the solution and check that errors are resolved or not and if we solved one library issues then some another library issues starting up and we are in the loop of this process from last 7 days

Can someone please help us that what is the correct process to upgrade angular so we can rid of unnecessary issues, I really thankful if someone guides me in the right direction

Comment: Whats the final version you want to upgrade your angular project? Just 4 to 5 ?

Comment: @RicardoMachado - Yes

Comment: Anyway, you have to check each of your thirdy-party packages and check what's the correct version that works on Angular 5. 
After doing it, you still getting errors, so edit your post and show us some screenshots about the errors you are getting.